# Log explicit statements from a session user to Unified Auditing in Oracle 12c

Tags: database, oracle, audit-logging

Trying to log all actions / statements run by a specific session user on an Oracle 12c database, using the relatively new Unified Auditing logging evironnment.

The audit policy is defined as the following:

```
CREATE AUDIT POLICY log_test
ACTIONS ALL
WHEN 'SYS_CONTEXT(''USERENV'', ''SESSION_USER'') = ''JOSTEIN'''
EVALUATE PER SESSION;
```

This does log statements run, but it also logs *a* *lot* of other statements which were not run explicitly by the session user.

Is there a way to include explicit statements only for the WHEN clause?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote: "This does log statements run, but it also logs a lot of other statements which were not run explicitly by the session user."

You need to check from the unified_audit_trail view what was in the column "unified_audit_policies" for these other statements

Answer (score 0):

First please make sure Unified auditing is enabled

```
select * from v$option where PARAMETER = 'Unified Auditing';
```

Your create audit policy statement is correct, so it should audit only the user JOSTEIN

After that enable the audit policy

```
audit policy log_test;
```

You can view the audit policy options as below

```
col audit_option format A20
col policy_name format A18
select POLICY_NAME, AUDIT_OPTION, CONDITION_EVAL_OPT
from   AUDIT_UNIFIED_POLICIES
where  POLICY_NAME ='LOG_TEST';
```

Verify your audit policy is enabled

```
col user_name format A10
col policy_name format A18
select POLICY_NAME, ENABLED_OPT, USER_NAME, SUCCESS, FAILURE
from AUDIT_UNIFIED_ENABLED_POLICIES
where POLICY_NAME ='LOG_TEST';
```

After performing any audited operation you may check the audited data using

```
col action_name format A16
col policy_name format A18
col system_privilege_used format A20
select DBUSERNAME, ACTION_NAME, SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE_USED
from unified_audit_trail
where DBUSERNAME = 'JOSTEIN';
```

This should give you audit result of that specific user.

You can view more on the same using the below link

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/security/sec_uni_audit/sec_uni_audit.html